# How to close/answer a question based on a mistake?

Tags: discussion

As a general, how should one answer questions that are based on printing mistakes?

E.g. Questions like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35490/501) - should they be:

- Answered: *Your Siddur is wrong.* How would one prove this? How much research should one provide to prove one's case?
- Deleted: What reason would one give?
- Left unanswered with the comments explaining the problem? (Like this example has.) This wastes a lot of time when looking for unanswered questions to answer.

Sort of related to [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4089/501), but I'm not sure my question has the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think that an answer that demonstrates, [however it can](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/716/2), that a basis of the question [is incorrect](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4109/2), would be valuable to the asker and anyone with the same false premise and is therefore the ideal response, within our Q&A model.